# What is this wire mesh around this car?

Tags: wire

Spotted at about 9500 feet in the Sangre de Christo mountains near Westcliffe, Colorado in early September on a very warm day.  The vehicle was spotted two nights later in the same place.

[image: Vehicle with wire mesh surrounding it]

Comment: Maybe its a particularly badly behaved car that needs caged up to stop it running away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An animal defense system - some can cause lots of damage...

Comment: I was going to say that maybe it works in food service, but your answer is better @SolarMike

Comment: Also maybe to keep animals out so the car doesn't damage them.  When I was little we had some outdoor cats that liked to sleep in the warm engine bay.  Didn't always work out well for them.

Comment: Where I live some of the rodents chew the wiring... very expensive to repair in some cases.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm guessing an animal incident occurred to this person or someone this person knows.  This person is either paranoid or I am reckless in the face of danger.